# problema de conexion laravel y sql server

Tags: php, laravel

necesito de su ayuda soy nuevo con sqlserver, pero me encontre el problema que al momento de intentar acceder a una base de datos este me tira varios errores ya eh intentado de todo, les muestro mi configuración de laravel y php.

ARCHIVO .ENV

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=MIURL
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=DBSERVER
DB_USERNAME=USER1
DB_PASSWORD=
```

ARCHIVO DATABASE.PHP

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'MIURL'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DBSERVER'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'USER1'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
           'options' => [PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE => true],
            
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
        ],
```

MI ARCHIVO PHP.INI

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv
extension=php_sqlsrv
```

TENGO INSTALADO MICROSOFT ODBC DRIVER 11 Y 18
PERO SIGO OBTENIENDO ERRORES DE CONEXION COMO POR EJEMPLO:

`Error de conexión: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.`

Por favor amigos ayudenme

probe con muchas consultas utilizando pdo pero no me ah funcionado nada, todo me da error.

Comment: Y si descomentas `// 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false')` y lo cambias a `true` el ultimo parámetro ????

Comment: eres un genio amigo, te debo un café gracias.

Comment: http://img.desmotivaciones.es/201201/sakuragi2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

un cordial saludo.

Lei tu codigo y pues aparentemente todo esta en orden. Pienso que el mensaje de error que estás viendo indica que hay un problema de certificación SSL al intentar establecer una conexión a una base de datos SQL Server. El error específico "La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía" sugiere que el sistema no confía en la entidad emisora del certificado SSL que está utilizando el servidor SQL.

Pues estuve investigando y encontré algunas posibles soluciones al problema:

1. Actualizar el controlador ODBC: Asegúrate de que estás utilizando la última versión del controlador ODBC para SQL Server. Las actualizaciones a menudo corrigen problemas de compatibilidad y seguridad.
2. Verificar la cadena de certificación: Asegúrate de que el certificado del servidor SQL esté emitiendo la cadena de certificación completa, incluidos los certificados intermedios y el certificado raíz. Si falta algún eslabón en la cadena, podría causar problemas de confianza.
3. Importar el certificado: Si tienes acceso al certificado SSL del servidor SQL, puedes intentar importarlo manualmente en el almacén de certificados de la máquina cliente. Esto podría ayudar a que el sistema confíe en la entidad emisora del certificado.
4. Actualizar las autoridades de certificación confiables: Asegúrate de que las autoridades de certificación confiables en tu máquina estén actualizadas. Si el certificado está emitido por una entidad confiable pero no se encuentra en la lista de confianza de tu sistema, podrías necesitar agregarla.

Espero que logres encontrar alguna solución.

Answer (score 0):

Configurar la opción 'encrypt': Dentro de tu configuración de conexión en Laravel, puedes habilitar la opción 'encrypt' para cifrar la conexión SSL. Descomenta la línea 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'), en tu configuración y asegúrate de que DB_ENCRYPT esté configurado correctamente en tu archivo .env (o directamente en el archivo de configuración).

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).